# Regex: how to limit max number of integers in an alphanumeric field

Tags: javascript, jquery

My instructions are that a user can type all characters into the field except these:

```
~`!@#$%^&*()_+={}[]|\;"',<>?
```

The maxlength is 60.

The integers in the string must not be more than 10.

So for example, if user pastes into input:

```
INV-123-RT-123456789-TR-123
```

Then the regex should output:

```
INV-123-RT-1234567-TR-
```

Here's my code.  I am stuck on deleting the extra integers from the end of the string.

```
 $('.isInvoiceNumber').on("input", function(e) {

  var pos = this.selectionStart;

  var str = $(this).val().replace(/[\~\`\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)_\+\=\{\}\[\]\|\\\;\"\'\,\<\>\?]/g, '').replace(/\.{2,}/g, '.'); 

  var digits = str.replace(/[^0-9]/g,"").length;
  if ( digits>10 ) {
    // ??
  }

  var len = str.length;
  $(this).val(str);
  this.selectionEnd = pos - ( len-str.length );
});
```

--> 
Here's the **Codepen** to make it easy:
https://codepen.io/btn-ninja/pen/vJrXbX

Thanks!

Comment: You can use HTML5 numeric field with max attribute.

Comment: "all characters except these ..." is a lot more than just alphanumeric characters. And what is meant by "The integers must not be more than 15"? Should it contain at most 15 digits? (yet your code contains `digits>10`)

Comment: Thank you TiiJ7, I have edited the question for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```js
function limit( str ) {
  var patt = /[~`!@#\$%\^&\*()_\+={}\[\]\|\;\"\'\,\<\>\?]/g;
  var strWithoutSpecialChars = str.replace(patt,'') ;
  var count = 0, result = '', numberDigit = 0 ;
  for (var i = 0; i < strWithoutSpecialChars.length && count < 60; i++ ) {
    var ch = strWithoutSpecialChars[i] ;
    if ( /\d/.test(ch) ) {
      numberDigit++;
      if ( numberDigit < 15 ) { result += ch; count++ ; }
      else { continue ; }
    }
    else { result += ch; count++ ; }
  }
 return result ;
}

var longText = 'Miusov, 5699999999as a man man of breeding and 555deilcacy, could 98955not but feel some inwrd qualms, when he reached the Father Superiors with Ivan: he felt ashamed of havin lost his temper. He felt that he ought to have disdaimed that despicable wretch, Fyodor Pavlovitch, too much to have been upset by him in Father Zossimas cell, and so to have forgotten himself. "Teh monks were not to blame, in any case," he reflceted, on the steps. "And if theyre decent people here (and the Father Superior, I understand, is a nobleman) why not be friendly and courteous withthem? I wont argue, Ill fall in with everything, Ill win them by politness, and show them that Ive nothing to do with that Aesop, thta buffoon, that Pierrot, and have merely been takken in over this affair, just as they have.';

var result = limit(longText) ;
console.log('Length : ' + result.length ) ;
console.log( 'String : ' + result ) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply check this in your if condition:

```
var str = str.substr(0, str.length-1);
```

It removes the last entered character from the input string.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
 $('.isInvoiceNumber').on("input", function(e) {

  var pos = this.selectionStart;

  var str = $(this).val().replace(/[\~\`\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)_\+\=\{\}\[\]\|\\\;\"\'\,\<\>\?]/g, '').replace(/\.{2,}/g, '.'); 

  var digits = str.replace(/[^0-9]/g,"").length;
  if ( digits>10 ) {
        str = str.substring(0, 10);
  }

  var len = str.length;
  $(this).val(str);
  this.selectionEnd = pos - ( len-str.length );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean input validation? Something like this?:

```js
//use 'keydown' to prevent copy pasting invalid values
var inputLength = 0;
$('#invoice').on('keydown', function(){inputLength = $(this).val().length});
//check against criteria set upon input
$('#invoice').on('keyup', function(){
  if($(this).val().length>60 || $(this).val().match(/[0-9]/g).length>15 || $(this).val().match(/[^\w^0-9]/)){
    $(this).val($(this).val().slice(0,inputLength-$(this).val().length));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="invoice"></input>
```